# Что быстрее конкатенация строк плюсом или String.format()?

Tags: java

Какой из этих кодов выполнится быстрее?

```
"<th>" + cell.toString() + "</th>"
```

или

```
String.format("<th>%s</th>", cell.toString())
```

Comment: @abg, a что вам мешает самому проверить это?

Comment: Вот как раз на эту тему: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: `new StringBuilder().append("<th>").append(cell).append("</th>").toString();` выполнится все равно быстрее...

Comment: заменять `+` на stringbuilder нет особой причины - компилятор сам умеет это делать. Правда оно не включится, если это будет так `for (..) { s += 'x';}

Comment: @Barmaley, ЕМНИП выражения типа `"<th>" + cell.toString() + "</th>"` как раз при компиляции оптимизируются через `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Nofate, для однократного исполнения кода Вы правы. Если же результирующая строка строится в цикле, то надо делать через StringBuilder (или если точно известно, что у нас нет нескольких потоков, то лучше (быстрее) StringBuffer), создаваемый **перед** циклом. Компилятор сам не доходит до такой оптимизации.

Comment: @Nofate смотря какой компилятор, да и полагаться на компилятор не есть айс

Comment: Ради интереса предлагаю посмотреть презентацию Алексея Шипелева на JPoint 2015 [Катехизис java.lang.String](http://2015.javapoint.ru/presentations/jpoint-April2015-string-catechism.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конкатенация быстрее. String.format внутри себя тянет очень много.

Answer (score 4):

Наверное, format обычно медленнее при определённых обстоятельствах. Но это не существенно.

Могу поспорить, что этот участок кода -- не самая большая проблема производительности всей программы. В этом случае вы должны выбрать не тот кусок, который даст микроскопическое улучшение времени выполнения, а тот, который проще, яснее, легче в поддержке и расширении, и лучше выражает вашу мысль. (Это может оказаться в принципе тот же самый кусок. А может и нет.)

Оптимизируйте только те места, которые требуют оптимизации.

Comment: у меня был случай, когда как раз format очень сильно просаживал скорость работы (правда дело было на андроиде).

Comment: @VladD, это в общем то правильная идея, но на практике часто программу, при написании которой никто об оптимизации не думал, а в процессе ее эксплуатации возник вопрос об производительности, проще выбросить и написать с нуля.

Comment: @KoVadim: могу поспорить, что (1) format происходил в цикле, (2) после профилирования вы нашли источник просадки и пофиксили проблему за 2 минуты, (3) и дописали комментарий, почему именно в этом месте нужен такой код. Так что это по идее ничему не противоречит.

Comment: @avp: по моему опыту, если использовать сразу подходящие структуры данных (например, не моделировать большое множество массивом + линейный поиск + вставки в середину, а сразу взять `std::map` или `HashSet`), проблем в подавляющем большинстве случаев не возникает. Для того, чтобы можно было безболезненно подменить структуру данных при изменении требований, надо с самого начала спрятать её внутрь класса (maintainability же!)

Comment: код был следующий - с помощью format формировались select запросы к базе. Их вроде не много было. Цикла формально не было (ну если не считать цикла обработки сообщений:) ).

2) фиксил не две минуты - format'ы были по всему коду разбросаны. К тому же профайлер не сразу показал. Просаживал много GC.

3) просто на внутрикорпоративном вики написал, почему так не стоит делать.

Comment: @KoVadim: если обращение к format даже без цикла просаживает производительность сравнимо со скоростью запроса к базе (!!!), это однозначно баг, и его надо обходить. Надеюсь, ваш случай нетипичен.

Comment: я же пишу - основная проблема в том, что format создает много временных объектов, которые нагружают GC.

Comment: @KoVadim: тогда наверное проблема в GC. На других платформах ведь временные объекты -- не проблема? Ну и имплементацию format уж могли сделать для андроида потолковее. В любом случае, если расходы на один format не пренебрежимо малы по сравнению с расходами на запрос к базе данных -- что-то не так с платформой.

Comment: проблема конечно в GC. На других платфомах (которые используют java) временные объекты также могут быть проблемой.

>>  В любом случае, если расходы на один format не пренебрежимо малы по сравнению с расходами на запрос к базе данных -- что-то не так с платформой.

А база здесь ни при чем. здесь мог оказаться какой-нибудь логгер.

Comment: @VladD, " если использовать сразу **подходящие** структуры данных "

так и я о том же самом. Сразу надо думать что будет эффективным.

Answer (score 1):

Также вы можете почитать об этом [здесь](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat) (почти в самом конце). Правда, это C#, но, думаю, все равно найдете немало полезного.